# How to redirect logout page to an extern url

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Doing from this way, everything just work fine: module from vendor/costumer-contact/view/frontend/templates/logout.phtml:

from:

```
        "Magento_Customer/js/logout-redirect": {
            "url": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl())) ?>"
        }
    }
}
```

to this

```
<p><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('You have signed out and will go to our homepage in 5 seconds.')) ?></p>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Customer/js/logout-redirect": {
                "url": "<?= ("https://exemple.ao") ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

How to create a custom module for this extension ?

I want to redirect to an external url

Comment: Ok so after logout, you want to send customer to another website apart from magento?

Comment: Yes, that is what i want

Comment: in above code do you face any issue?

Comment: No, but i really want to create a module. and i did that but nothing has changed.
The module i created like always in: app -> code Mymodule -> UrlChanging

Comment: Then you can create the module and overide this things into this one.

Comment: I just tried, but nothing is changed. may u help me how to do it?